# Protected view in Office 2010 hangs and can't be turned off

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2010

I'm using Office 2010 SP2 on Windows 10. Whenever I open an Excel or Word file, it hangs at "Opening in protected view".

To resolve this issue, I went into Trust Center, disabled trusted view as so:

[image]

I also disabled blocking for all file types here:

[image]

However, when I try to open Excel files, Excel still tries to open it in Protected View, and hangs on the loading screen here:

[image]

How can I resolve this? I don't need protected view, so I'd like to just disable it entirely.

Comment: Could this just be a problem with your Excel installation? Try reinstalling it?

Comment: @Excellll It does it with Word as well, but I'll just try repairing and/or reinstalling the whole suite.

Answer (score 0):

For unrelated reasons, I downgraded Windows 10 to Windows 7 on this machine and reinstalled Office, where the problem no longer presented. I suspect the issue was related to Windows 10's relationship with Office 2010, but I can't be sure.